# Get IFC schema version

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, ifc

Opening an *.ifc file we can find "File_Schema" in the Header, for example:
HEADER;
...
FILE_SCHEMA (('IFC4'));
ENDSEC;

We are downloading IFC stream file and it would be nice to know the file schema version for it.
Is it somehow possible to get this information via DataManagement API?

Comment: It sounds you wanted to know File_Schema before downloading IFC from storage of Autodesk (your own bucket or Autodesk cloud products such as BIM 360)? I do not see such web service/response is available. If the IFC has been downloaded, you can simply open the file and check its FILE_SCHEMA

Answer (score 1):

This is already an old post, but just to mention that for those who download the file before any other operation: once downloaded, the following command can be used (on a Unix-like environment) to get exactly the IFC schema (e.g. "IFC2X3", "IFC4"):

```
grep "^FILE_SCHEMA" file.ifc | cut -d"'" -f2
```

Of course this command can be integrated in a program written in Node.js for example (using childProcess.exec), or any other programming language. Note that this is usually faster than streaming the file and searching in it, or even using a language-specific library to "grep" the file, especially for big IFC files.